# Is there a better solution of this RxJS epic stream?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have a redux state using redux-observable's epics.

I need to solve showing a message after a user deletes an object or more objects.

There are two ways how to delete an object:

1. by action `deleteObject(id: string)` which call `deleteObjectFulfilled` action
2. by action `deleteObjects(ids: Array<string>)` which call `N * deleteObject(id: string)` actions

I want to show **only one message with a count** of deleted messages after every success "deleting action".

My final solution of this epic is:

```js
export const showDeleteInformationEpic = action$ =>
  combineLatest(
    action$.pipe(ofType(DELETE_OBJECT_FULFILLED)),
    action$.pipe(
      ofType(DELETE_OBJECTS),
      switchMap(({ meta: { ids } }) =>
        action$.pipe(
          ofType(DELETE_OBJECT_FULFILLED),
          skip(ids.length - 1),
          map(() => ids.length),
          startWith('BATCH_IN_PROGRESS'),
          take(2),
        ),
      ),
      startWith(1),
    ),
  ).pipe(
    startWith([null, null]),
    pairwise(),
    map(([[, previousCount], [, currentCount]]) => 
      (previousCount === 'BATCH_IN_PROGRESS') 
        ? currentCount 
        : isNumber(currentCount) ? 1 : currentCount),
    filter(isNumber),
    map((count) => throwInfo('objectDeleted', { count })),
  );
```

Can you see any better solution of this?

Answer (score 1):

There is more simple solution if I use only `deleteObjects(Array<string>)` for both cases..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of firing multiple actions, you can create and dispatch a single action `DELETE_MULTIPLE` and pass all the `id`(s) in the payload.

This way your `effects` will be a lot cleaner since you only have to `subscribe` to `DELETE_MANY` action and additionally, it will prevent multiple `store` dispatches.